# Magento Custom Payment iFrame Module Error

Tags: magento, module, payment

I am attempting to code a Magento Payments Module that will call an iFrame rather than the standard CC block. However when when running the code below I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setMethod() on a non-object in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Helper/Data.php on line 106

Config.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
       <Lynch_Peach>
<!-- declare module's version information for database updates -->
          <version>0.1.0</version>
       </Lynch_Peach>
    </modules>

    <global>
    <blocks>
        <peach>
            <class>Lynch_Peach_Block</class>
        </peach>
    </blocks>


        <models>
            <peach>
  <class>Lynch_Peach_Model</class>
            </peach>
        </models>

<!-- declare resource setup for new module -->
        <resources>
<!-- resource identifier -->
            <peach_setup>
<!-- specify that this resource is a setup resource and used for upgrades -->
                <setup>
<!-- which module to look for install/upgrade files in -->
                    <module>Lynch_Peach</module>
                </setup>
<!-- specify database connection for this resource -->
                <connection>
<!-- do not create new connection, use predefined core setup connection -->
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </peach_setup>
            <peach_write>
                <connection>
                  <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </peach_write>
            <peach_read>
               <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
              </connection>
            </peach_read>
        </resources>
    </global>

<!-- declare default configuration values for this module -->
    <default>
<!-- 'payment' configuration section (tab) -->
        <payment>
<!-- 'peach' configuration group (fieldset) -->
            <peach>
<!-- by default this payment method is inactive -->
                <active>0</active>
<!-- model to handle logic for this payment method -->
                <model>peach/paymentMethod</model>
<!-- order status for new orders paid by this payment method -->
                <order_status>pending</order_status>
<!-- default title for payment checkout page and order view page -->
                <title>Peach Payments</title>

                <cctypes>VI,MC</cctypes>

                <payment_action>authorize_capture</payment_action>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
            </peach>
         </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

Payment Method.php

```
<?php
class Lynch_Peach_Model_PaymentMethod extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cc
{

    protected $_code = 'peach';
    protected $_formBlockType = 'peach/form';
    protected $_isGateway               = false;
    protected $_canAuthorize            = false;
    protected $_canCapture              = false;
    protected $_canCapturePartial       = false;
    protected $_canRefund               = false;
    protected $_canVoid                 = false;
    protected $_canUseInternal          = false;
    protected $_canUseCheckout          = true;
    protected $_canUseForMultishipping  = false;
    protected $_canSaveCc = false;


  public function createFormBlock($name)
    {
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('peach/form', $name)
            ->setMethod('peach')
            ->setPayment($this->getPayment())
            ->setTemplate('peach/form.phtml');

        return $block;
    }

}
?>
```

Form.php:

```
<?php
class Lynch_Peach_Block_Form extends Mage_Payment_Block_Form
{
    // {{{ _construct()
    /**
     * _construct() 
     */    
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $$this->setTemplate( 'peach/form.phtml' );
    }
    // }}}
}

?>
```

Comment: Looks fine.
Where do you have this error?
Where do you use `createFormBlock` function?

Answer (score 0):

You have double $$ in form constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by applying the following changes.

```
protected $_formBlockType = 'peach/form';
```

change above like folowing,

```
protected $_formBlockType = 'peach/Form';
```

usually this doesn't matter if you are running your application in Windows environment. But this may be issue when running in non-windows environment.